# Why title, description goes off the screen and date not showing properly in constrainlayout

Tags: android, textview, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I am developing news app  and I have implemented constraint layout with  card view but title description not showing and title and description goes of the screen in real device  but in layout inspector in android studio it is showing fine

below my view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="article"
            type="com.example.newsworldwide.model.Article" />
    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="16dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="8dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">



        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/articleImage"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:elevation="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:imageUrl="@{article.urlToImage}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleTitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="Mini olive pies by Vaggelio"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.65"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/articleImage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleDescription"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:text="This is the most information savory snack that I have ever seen!!!"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/articleTitle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/articleTitle" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/articleDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="48dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="01.02.2022"
            android:textColor="#FF9935"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

below my  recyclerview layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="491dp"
        android:layout_height="826dp"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/news_item" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

following screenshot from layout inspector in android studio
[image: screenshot from layout inspector in android studio]

following screenshot of the app  from real device
[image: real device screenshot]

I want to know where exactly I am making mistake what I have to do in order to show title description and date so that it can fit screen perfectly

Comment: The title should be OK, but the description misses an end constraint .. Try [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EM1cUqOZVXsd9VQ044e5kgBOgNLh6TJ1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have tried your answer did not work

Answer (score 1):

I think the tour item not the problem.  Check the size of the `RecyclerView`.

Comment: can you check my recyclerview code I have added

Comment: change size recyclerview
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: yes but data overlapping

Comment: add to text view "articleDescription"
 -> app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/articleTitle"

Answer (score 1):

I've made some tweaks to your xml files 
RecyclerView layout should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.506"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        tools:listitem="@layout/news_item" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="260dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Your mistake was right here:

```
android:layout_width="491dp"
android:layout_height="826dp"
```

putting exact values for layout_width and layout_height is almost never a good idea when trying to build a responsive UI. Instead try using match_parent (matches the screen width) or wrap_content (takes as much space as it needs) in your layout_width/height.

Also I found one more thing wrong with `news_item.xml`

`articleDescription` TextView should have this parameter:

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/articleTitle"
```

this parameter will make sure, that your textView end where the parent view ends, means not going out of screen.